How to dynamically configure stubbing etc. for a WireMock testcontainer?
All the examples I've seen so far configure stubbings etc. of a WireMock testcontainer statically at definition.
How can I configure it dynamically via stubFor etc.?

You should be able to configure a running wiremock server using the java client by specifying first
WireMock.configureFor("my.remote.host", 8000);

and then using stubFor etc. as usual.
